# Looking for guidance in using standard Polymer Core and Paper components (and associated events) in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, events, attributes, polymer

First of all many thanks for the incredible source of information that you are providing to people like me.

I am visiting this site very often and most often finding the answer I need, but this is this is the first time I post a question, so please accept my apologies if I don't fully conform to rules.

Here is my issue:

- I am "playing" with Dart Editor and Polymer to try to understand if I could use these technologies in my job moving forward
- I was able to import the Polymer Core and Paper components in Dart Editor and to install polymer.dart
- I was able to create a simple web page with a "core-selector" and to add some Dart code to handle a click on this component
- I can't find how to listen using Dart code for component-specific event ("core-activate" & "core-select" here) and how to read component-specific attributes ("selected" & "multi" here)
- I don't seem to be able to find good examples showing how to use "standard" polymer components in a web app created Dart Editor
- I could find material on how to create my own polymer components using polymer.dart but I would just like to use standard components

I understand both Polymer and Dart are young but I can't imagine the clever brains at Google not having a solution or plans on this.

Regards and many thanks again.

Sebastien

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that Polymer and Dart are young. Dart is quite mature, Polymer is not even beta but also not so young anymore. The problem are the core- and paper-elements. They are very new and developed in JavaScript and the Polymer.dart team just created a code generator that wraps the JS core- and paper-elements in Polymer.dart elements. This process is only available since a few days and there are several issues which are yet to be solved.

I think you should provide a concrete example in your question of what you can't get working. Basically Polymer.dart core- and paper-elements work exactly as other Polymer.dart elements. So it's hard to know what to explain.